# Draw a square in opengl at mouse position

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to draw a simple square wherever I press the left mouse button using opengl/glut. My program runs perfectly except for the part where it does **not** draw the square where I click the left mouse button :). Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <glut.h>

GLsizei WIDTH = 1300, HEIGHT = 700;
GLsizei MOUSEx, MOUSEy;
GLfloat SIDE=1;

GLfloat RED[3] = {1,0,0};
GLfloat GREEN[3] = {0,1,0};
GLfloat BLUE[3] = {0,0,1};
GLfloat WHITE[3] = {1,1,1};
GLfloat BLACK[3] = {0,0,0};
GLfloat YELLOW[3] = {1,1,0};
GLfloat CYAN[3] = {0,1,1};
GLfloat MAGENTA[3] = {1,0,1};

void drawSquare(int x, int y)
{
    glColor3fv(YELLOW);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(x+SIDE, y+SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x-SIDE, y+SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x-SIDE, y-SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x+SIDE, y-SIDE,0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void drawSquare1()
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    glColor3fv(BLUE);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(x+SIDE, y+SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x-SIDE, y+SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x-SIDE, y-SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(x+SIDE, y-SIDE,0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void display (void) {
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
    drawSquare1();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape (int w, int h) {
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    WIDTH=w;
    HEIGHT=h;
}

void setX(int x)
{
    MOUSEx=x;
}

void setY(int y)
{
    MOUSEy=y;
}

void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)   
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        drawSquare(MOUSEx,HEIGHT-MOUSEy);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)   
    {
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition (10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow ("New Window");
    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    //glutMotionFunc(drawSquare);
    glutMainLoop ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In short words: OpenGL is not a scene graph. That means that those drawing commands issued in the mouse handler don't create some kind of "persistency".

Instead clicking the mouse you should store the position in a list/array and draw the squares from the values in that list in the display function.

Comment: It's not about the amount of stuff you draw. This is a conceptual thing. OpenGL is "just" a sophisticated drawing API. Once you sent geometry to OpenGL is rasterizes and forgets about it.

Comment: I understand, but I just saw another piece of code in which the person was drawing by clicking the mouse twice (for opposite corners) and he was able to draw multiple rectangles without using any arrays or lists, just four global variables for the two x,y positions. This seems to be nearly what I am trying to do also.

Comment: @Rizwan: I suspect that person just didn't clear the OpenGL framebuffer and did not use double buffering (or render to texture was used). The problem is, that this is rather unstable, as simply moving another window over the OpenGL window will clear it. OpenGL is not doing persistency for you, you'll have to do it yourself. Code like the one you're referring to is one example of bad OpenGL tutorials I'm extremely upset with. Please consider my advice: Don't Do It That Way!

Answer (score 4):

I am fresh to this Coding But I done it.

Here is My Code It will Work.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
GLsizei MOUSEx=0, MOUSEy=0;
GLfloat SIDE=50;
GLfloat BLUE[3] = {0,0,1};

void drawSquare1()
{
    glColor3fv(BLUE);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(MOUSEx, MOUSEy,0);
        glVertex3f(MOUSEx+SIDE, MOUSEy,0);
        glVertex3f(MOUSEx+SIDE, MOUSEy+SIDE,0);
        glVertex3f(MOUSEx, MOUSEy+SIDE,0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}   

void display(void)
{   
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    drawSquare1();
    glFlush();
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{   
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
     //gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glOrtho(0.0,1368,768,0,-1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void spindisplay(void)
{       
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void setX(int x)
{
    MOUSEx=x;
}

void setY(int y)
{
    MOUSEy=y;
}
void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)   
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        //drawSquare(MOUSEx,HEIGHT-MOUSEy);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)   
    {
        exit(1);   // To Exit the Program
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1366,768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("Moving squares");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutIdleFunc(spindisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code taken from [OpenGL Projects](http://www.openglprojects.in/2015/01/draw-squares-opengl-size-option-sound.html). Try to execute this and I think the problem with your drawing squares in OpenGL would be solve easily. If any question kindly ask.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
    #include<glut.h>
    GLsizei wh=500,ww=500;
    GLfloat size=3.0;

    void display()
    {
    glFlush();
    }

    void myInit()
    {
        glViewport(0,0,ww,wh);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0.0,(GLdouble)ww,0.0,(GLdouble)wh);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    }

    void myReshape(GLsizei w,GLsizei h)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0.0,(GLdouble)w,0.0,(GLdouble)h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glViewport(0,0,w,h);
        ww=w;
        wh=h;
    }

    void drawSquare(int x,int y)
    {

        y=wh-y;
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(x+size,y+size);
        glVertex2f(x-size,y+size);
        glVertex2f(x-size,y-size);
        glVertex2f(x+size,y-size);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();

    }

    void size_menu(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
        case 2: size=size*2;
                break;
        case 3:if(size>1) size=size/2;
        break;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void top_menu(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
        case 1:exit(0);break;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void myMouse(int button,int state,int x,int y)
    {
        if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON&&state==GLUT_DOWN)
        drawSquare(x,y);
        if(button==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON&&state==GLUT_DOWN)
            exit(0);
    }

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
        int sub_menu;
        glutInit(&argc,argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
        glutCreateWindow("Hierarchical Menus to Draw Squares");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        myInit();
        glutMouseFunc(myMouse);
        sub_menu=glutCreateMenu(size_menu);
        glutAddMenuEntry("Increase Square Size",2);
        glutAddMenuEntry("Decrease Square Size",3);
        glutCreateMenu(top_menu);
        glutAddMenuEntry("Quit",1);
        glutAddSubMenu("Resize",sub_menu);
        glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
        glutReshapeFunc(myReshape);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```